# Яндекс блок «Поделиться». Ошибка одноклассников, и не отображается счётчик других соц.сетей

Tags: javascript, share, ya-share2

Когда пытаемся шарить однаклассники, выдаёт ошибку доступа. Нормально шарится только вк и фейсбук, также на них нормально показывается счётчик. На других соц.сетях счётчик не работает. Он вроде бы активируется, но при перезагрузки страницы сбрасывается. 
[https://altaibear.com/ru/магазин/фиточай-похудение/](https://altaibear.com/ru/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BD/%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5/)

Comment: Опубликовал запись 2 раза - всё норм. Никак спамите?

Comment: Ничего не спамлю, как не работало, так и не работает нефига. Счётчик работает только на вк и фейсбук, однаклассники вообще в ошибку доступа выпадают.

Comment: Да и какой смысл спамить тут? Если мне только ты отвелил спустя пару дней. Тут походу вообще народу нет.

Comment: Никто не отвечает потому, что вопрос оформлен, мягко говоря, неидеально. Во-первых, тут две несвязанные проблем – здесь так не принято, на каждую проблема нужно заводить отдельный вопрос. Во-вторых, сами проблемы описаны очень невнятно. "Когда пытаемся шарить однаклассники, выдаёт ошибку доступа" – кто выдаёт, кому, где? Во всплывающем окне вы это видите или в консоли? "Ошибка доступа" – это текст или 401 код ответа? Вы не потрудились описать вашу проблему – людям не интересно выпытывать детали.

Comment: Я пока могу ответить только про "при перезагрузки страницы сбрасывается". В документации этот момент оговорен: https://tech.yandex.ru/share/doc/dg/troubleshooting-docpage/#reset

Comment: Да я бы навтыкал картинок куча, если можно было бы.

Comment: Вот фото данной ошибки с однаклассниками http://i066.radikal.ru/1707/b7/0e2a3848efad.jpg

Comment: По поводу счётчика, уже много дней прошло, не обновлялся. Можете даже сами попробовать. Также по поводу однаклассников, бывает доступ появляется иногда, потом снова исчезает.